# PHP and MySQL - error 1062

Tags: php, mysql

I'm uploading a form and inserting its data into a table in MySQL. The primary key is the only field that must be unique. In the following code I check if the error number is 1062 (duplicate entry) and display a custom message for that case. But when I enter unique data into the table, I'm still getting the error sometimes. Strangely, it's only appearing now and then, but I'm 100 sure the values are not the same...

```
$success = mysqli_stmt_execute( $stmt );
$errorCode = mysqli_errno( $con );

if ($success) { 
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $uniquePath);

?>

<div id="response">
    <p>Success! The user has been added to the database</p>
</div>

<?
} else if ($errorCode == 1062) {
?>

<div id="response">
    <p>
     The user could not be added to the database.
      The ID already exists!
    </p>
</div>

<? 
} else {
?>

<div id="response">
     <p>
      The user could not be added to the database.
      MySQL error code: <? echo $errorCode ?>
    </p>
</div>

<?
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The SQL-relevant code looks like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users ( id, photo_path) VALUES (?, ?)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare( $con, $sql );
mysqli_stmt_bind_param( $stmt, 'is', $_POST['id'], $uniquePath);
```

Is there something simple I'm overlooking here?

Comment: 1. What is the table schema 2. Provide an example of data that causes the error

Comment: You've left out pretty much all the *relevant* code.

Comment: Can we see the form/other code/SQL that is getting used? Also I'd suggest not using short tags. PHP should be opened with <?php

Comment: if you need uniq ID why do you not use [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) for it ?